# Why is $\mathbb{Z}_{100}$ bad for cryptography and how can it exploited.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, cryptography

I read that fields like $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ given $p$ is prime ensures that the key is "equally distributed". This makes it hard to reverse engineer and find any exploitable properties. I want to know what these properties are.
For example, how can one deduce or find any additional information if the field was  $\mathbb{Z}_{100}$. I know the basics of Finite Fields and why they're needed in cryptography. I need a simple explanation why $\mathbb{Z}_{100}$ isn't desirable.

Comment: Because $100$ is not prime.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_{100}$ is not a field. So if you know why finite fields are necessary, you know why $\mathbb{Z}_{100}$ is insufficient.

Comment: I do recognize that. But 100 not being prime means that certain properties show up which is make it undesirable for cryptography. I wanted to know what they are. I'm essentially asking "Z100 is undesirable. So that must mean there exist certain methods to render it useless for encryption. What are these methods to exploit Z100"

Comment: @Artaxerxes You can't invert all the members of $\mathbb{Z_{100}}$ (this is what 'it's not a field' means here). So many of the computations often used for cryptography in finite fields can't even be carried out in the first place. It's not a question of security, it's a question of functionality.

Comment: The private key $d$ is easily discovered from the public key $e$ since it suffices to compute $d = e^{-1} \bmod 40$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki But we could always choose numbers whose inverse do exist in the <s>field</s> ring. This was my exact doubt. Can you please elaborate a little more

Comment: It sounds like you may be conflating the notion of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ — that is, the group of numbers modulo $p$ (which turns out to be a field) with the notion of a finite field in general (e.g., the field with 25 elements, which bears only a passing resemblance to $\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: If there are numbers whose inverses don't exist, _it's not a field_ in the first place. It's a ring; there are computations that can be carried out in rings as well, but many of the schemes for cryptography do _not_ carry over. You can choose individual numbers, but you can't ensure that e.g. elliptic curve computations will give you non-invertible elements.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Would be possible to do anything useful with rings at all ?

Comment: @Artaxerxes Absolutely — there have been several cryptographic schemes designed over rings. (For instance, there are some over matrix rings). But security is more about the algorithm (for the most part) than the specific mathematical structures it uses. (Of course, it's usually the properties of those structures that let us analyze the security of the algorithm!)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks. That clarified a lot for me because I assumed it was more about the properties of the mathematical structures. So couldnt figure why a ring like $\mathbb{Z}_{100}$ would be useless compared to finite fields

Comment: You're very welcome! It is a topic well worth further digging into; I'd encourage you to keep learning!

Comment: Well, with $\mathbb Z_{100}$ you can create Multi-Prime RSA, though the modulus size will be too small to be secure.